# what is Flags used for?

Tags: android, flags

Would someone explain me the role of flags in functions like setFlags? What exactly does this word mean in that situation...?

My example is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(new RenderView(this));
}
```

I'd like to know what is setFlags used for?

I've read the API documentation, but I haven't understood that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply think of flags as features that you're applying to the object (in this case to the object `Window`), and they are represented as integers. You can apply the flags using the final variables in `Window` and `WindowManager.LayoutParams`.

`setFlags` replaces current flags.
`addFlags` appends more flags and does not replace the current ones.

Comment: Thanks. Simple and efficient answer. It helps me now.

Answer (score 1):

Basically setFlag() is used for as per our application requirement there are lots of flag available for that like

```
Window flag, Intent flag etc..
```

this flags is used some situation where we want to achieve some functionality at programitically for example

**`for Intent Flag`**

```
mintent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

which means all other activity will be clear which before you open at application execution.

As per your code **Window flag**

It will set your application screen full screen by programatically

Comment: @HellonCanellaMachado :;Sometimes in our android application  there are some situation comes which we have to handle many features in single applicaiotn so thats why we used flags ,for example in your application first  screen you have to show status bar for that you can set flag for that and now in same applicaiotn in second activity you have to show screen in fullscreen(without status bar ) so you can set flag for that and you can achieve it easily .. so In short for dynamic variation of our application flow and represent way we use flags for that

Comment: Are you telling me that there are other manners to set flags beyond the setflag function? If yes, could you cite other functions which I may use for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Applications screens say activity has some view associated with it. There are different ways to present your content, ie title bar, without title bar, full screen, auto screen lock, without auto screen lock... etc, to set this properties to your activity you tell the screen via setting this window flags, now there are some flags which need to be set before calling setContentView, so in your code you are trying to make your window full screen and to make flags effective you call setContentView explicitly.
To know more what you can do with your window to display content is different cases refer this : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html

Comment: Thanks guy. I'll think about that. You helped me.

Answer (score 0):

A flag is an **indicator** set to the operating system so it knows how you prefer to handle intents, for example, Flag is indicating that this PendingIntent can be used **only once**. For use with **getActivity**, **getBroadcast**, and **getService**.
If set, after send() is called on it, it will be automatically canceled for you and any future attempt to send through it will fail.